# Can we have our own FAQ?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

I've always found the "FAQ" at meta.stackoverflow to be useless.  I'd like to see a few pages that have "all" the information on a topic (e.g. reputation) w/out having to click back and forth to a list of links to other questions.

I'd like to have more details on reputation in that section, e.g. lost rep due to question migration (and "why did I lose 4 points about an hour ago? it seems to be due to a deleted answer when a question I'd answered was migrated), how to check your rep.

Comment: Are you referring to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931?

Comment: [It only took us about 2 years (and 3 drafts) to get around to this](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/2945/faq-rewrite-round-3)

Comment: Which is why we don't appreciate those who tell us that it should be revised, especially those with enough rep that they should have participated in the process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already do!

What would you like to see added to https://serverfault.com/faq specifically?

edit: based on your response, none of that is SF specific -- you should open this on meta.so if you want general /faq improvements that apply to all sites.

Comment: Maybe rep stuff isn't SF-specific, but one thing we're clearly going to need in the SF FAQ is a more thorough explanation of what questions are appropriate.  Just as soon as everyone agrees...